# Execute Thenable Functions after Deferred Object Resolves

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

How can a function returning a promise be run after functions returning `Deferred.promise()`?

I have an example of the problem on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jinhale/toqt66sq/3/). The alert messages are intended to end with "executed third?" as opposed to that alert displaying in the middle of the "executed first?" and "executed second?" alert messages.

Also, why does the sample code from JSFiddle fail to execute in the expected order?

Comment: I have a solution: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jinhale/toqt66sq/4/), but I still don't know why the solution works as opposed to the code in the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promises work by **return value**. If you don't return from a `then` there is no way for the promise to know it should wait for that value in subsequent `then`s.

When you do:

```
login()
.then(function() {
    getGuIdFromUser(); // return undefined implicit
})
.then(function() {
    getUserData('val'); // return undefined implicit
});
```

There is no way for the library to wait for the value since `undefined` is implicitly returned. If you add returns it works:

```
login()
.then(function() {
    return getGuIdFromUser();
})
.then(function() {
    return getUserData('val');
});
```

Note that `$.getJSON` already returns a promise so there is no need to wrap it in a `$.Deferred`.